# How to add an object created from a class to an array using a method created on its class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, oop, methods

I created a Book class which includes a method to add a single object to an array when a button is clicked. But when I click it, what gets added is the button itself from the DOM.

Here is the code:

```
class Book {
    constructor(title, author, year, poster){
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.year = year
        this.poster = poster
    }
    addToFavourite(){
        favouriteBooks.push(this)
    }

}
const favouriteBooks = []
const booksList = [ new Book('you don\'t know js', ' Kyle Simpson', 2014, 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41T5H8u7fUL._SX331_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg'), 
                    new Book('javascript the definitive guide', 'David Flanagan', 1996, 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wijnc-Y8L._SX379_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg'), 
                    new Book('Eloquent JavaScript', 'Marijn Haverbeke', 2011, 'https://eloquentjavascript.net/img/cover.jpg')
                ]


const renderBooks = (booksToRender)=>{  
    booksToRender.forEach(book =>{
        //elements to be created
        const bookContainer = document.createElement('article')
        const posterContainer = document.createElement('div')
        const poster = document.createElement('img')
        const bookTitle = document.createElement('h2')
        const bookYear = document.createElement('p')
        const bookAuthor = document.createElement('h3')
        const addToFavouriteBtn = document.createElement('button')

        //elements setup
        addToFavouriteBtn.addEventListener('click', book.addToFavourite)
        poster.src = book.poster
        bookTitle.textContent = book.title
        bookYear.textContent = book.year
        bookAuthor.textContent = book.author
        addToFavouriteBtn.textContent = 'Add to favourite'

        //elements render
        posterContainer.append(poster)
        bookContainer.append(posterContainer, bookTitle, bookYear, bookAuthor, addToFavouriteBtn)
        document.querySelector('main').append(bookContainer)
        
    })
}

renderBooks(booksList)
```

[image: here is the render of the mini app]

Comment: That's because the `this` refers to the button when the click event triggers and not to the book

Comment: You just saved my life. This issue had kept me from sleeping for about 3 nights (I'm still a rookie). THANKS A MILLION. Be blessed

Comment: Pls mark it as answer so future programmers find it when they need it, and happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `this` refers to the button when the click event triggers and not to the book, You need to bind the book to the method so `addToFavouriteBtn.addEventListener('click', book.addToFavourite)` should be `addToFavouriteBtn.addEventListener('click', book.addToFavourite.bind(book))` in order to make it work as expected

```js
class Book {
    constructor(title, author, year, poster){
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.year = year
        this.poster = poster
    }
    addToFavourite(){
        favouriteBooks.push(this)
        // just demonstration
        console.clear();
        console.log("---Favourite Books:---\n", favouriteBooks);
    }

}
const favouriteBooks = []
const booksList = [ new Book('you don\'t know js', ' Kyle Simpson', 2014, 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41T5H8u7fUL._SX331_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg'), 
                    new Book('javascript the definitive guide', 'David Flanagan', 1996, 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51wijnc-Y8L._SX379_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg'), 
                    new Book('Eloquent JavaScript', 'Marijn Haverbeke', 2011, 'https://eloquentjavascript.net/img/cover.jpg')
                ]


const renderBooks = (booksToRender)=>{  
    booksToRender.forEach(book =>{
        //elements to be created
        const bookContainer = document.createElement('article')
        const posterContainer = document.createElement('div')
        const poster = document.createElement('img')
        const bookTitle = document.createElement('h2')
        const bookYear = document.createElement('p')
        const bookAuthor = document.createElement('h3')
        const addToFavouriteBtn = document.createElement('button')

        //elements setup
        addToFavouriteBtn.addEventListener('click', book.addToFavourite.bind(book))
        poster.src = book.poster
        bookTitle.textContent = book.title
        bookYear.textContent = book.year
        bookAuthor.textContent = book.author
        addToFavouriteBtn.textContent = 'Add to favourite'

        //elements render
        posterContainer.append(poster)
        bookContainer.append(posterContainer, bookTitle, bookYear, bookAuthor, addToFavouriteBtn)
        document.querySelector('main').append(bookContainer)
        
    })
}

renderBooks(booksList)
```

```html
<main></main>
```